# Configuring NLog

Tags: c#, logging

I have this method:

```
public void AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()
{
    var filePath = _loggerModel.file_path_pattern.Replace("\\YYYY\\MM\\DD", "");
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    filePath += "\\" + dateTime.Year + "\\" + dateTime.Month.ToString() + "\\" + dateTime.Day;
    var filePattern = _loggerModel.file_name_pattern.Split('.');
    var dateTimeFormat = filePattern[1].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").ToString();
    var fileName = filePattern[0] + '.' + dateTime.ToString(dateTimeFormat) + "." + filePattern[2];

    var fileTargetWithStackTrace = new FileTarget(); 
    fileTargetWithStackTrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout + "|${stacktrace}";
    fileTargetWithStackTrace.Name = FILE_WITH_STACK_TRACE;
    fileTargetWithStackTrace.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    _nLogLoggingConfiguration.AddTarget(FILE_WITH_STACK_TRACE, fileTargetWithStackTrace);

    var fileTargetWithoutStacktrace = new FileTarget();
    fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.Name = FILE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE;
    fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout;
    fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    _nLogLoggingConfiguration.AddTarget(FILE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE, fileTargetWithoutStacktrace);
}
```

It seems that there are similarity inside the code, so I refactored it:

```
public void AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()
{
    var filePath = _loggerModel.file_path_pattern.Replace("\\YYYY\\MM\\DD", "");
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    filePath += "\\" + dateTime.Year + "\\" + dateTime.Month.ToString() + "\\" + dateTime.Day;
    var filePattern = _loggerModel.file_name_pattern.Split('.');
    var dateTimeFormat = filePattern[1].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").ToString();
    var fileName = filePattern[0] + '.' + dateTime.ToString(dateTimeFormat) + "." + filePattern[2];

    var fileTargetWithStackTrace = new FileTarget(); 
    fileTargetWithStackTrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout + "|${stacktrace}";
    fileTargetWithStackTrace.Name = FILE_WITH_STACK_TRACE;
    fileTargetWithStackTrace.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    AddFileTarget(fileTargetWithStackTrace);

    var fileTargetWithoutStacktrace = new FileTarget();
    fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.Name = FILE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE;
    fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout;
    fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    AddFileTarget(fileTargetWithoutStacktrace);
}

private void AddFileTarget(FileTarget fileTarget)
{
    _nLogLoggingConfiguration.AddTarget(fileTarget.Name, fileTarget);
}
```

Is it good enough?

**Edit**

By the comment, I made some changes.

```
 public void AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        String.Format("\\yyyy\\MM\\dd", dateTime);
        var filePath = _loggerModel.file_path_pattern.Replace("\\YYYY\\MM\\DD", "") + dateTime.ToString("\\\\yyyy\\\\MM\\\\dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var filePattern = _loggerModel.file_name_pattern.Split('.');
        var dateTimeFormat = filePattern[1].Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").ToString();
        var fileName = filePattern[0] + '.' + dateTime.ToString(dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "." + filePattern[2];

        var fileTargetWithStackTrace = new FileTarget();
        fileTargetWithStackTrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout + "|${stacktrace}";
        fileTargetWithStackTrace.Name = FILE_WITH_STACK_TRACE;
        fileTargetWithStackTrace.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        AddFileTarget(fileTargetWithStackTrace);

        var fileTargetWithoutStacktrace = new FileTarget();
        fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.Name = FILE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE;
        fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout;
        fileTargetWithoutStacktrace.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        AddFileTarget(fileTargetWithoutStacktrace);
    }

    private void AddFileTarget(FileTarget fileTarget)
    {
        _nLogLoggingConfiguration.AddTarget(fileTarget.Name, fileTarget);
    }
```

Comment: `Is it good enough?` Without knowing the requirements, there's no way to answer that.

Comment: Why are you refactoring? What do you hope to achieve?  Have you achieved this with the change?@Mast is correct, in that without knowing your goals we cannot tell if you have met them, but I feel that the change has not achieved any of the goals of refactoring [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498651/goals-of-refactoring)

Comment: @AlanT, the code itself was working. But I was told since `fileTargetWithStackTrace` and `fileTargetWithoutStacktrace` part are very similar. So we can combine them together with the clean code principle to reduce the length. The thing is I don't see the obvious change.

Comment: @Love There is a `lot` of repetitive coding in the method.  Refactoring it to remove the repetition is a good plan. Looking at the new version though, I don't see that any has been removed. All that has changed is wrapping a single line call with a method and then calling it twice.  Net addition to the code `AddFileTarget`. Net reduction in original method -  none.  It might be worth looking at moving **all** the lines in each block out to the new method.

Comment: @AlanT, that is exactly I wanted. I want to remove the repetition.

Comment: Is the project a standalone exe, web application or a class library (dll)?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, it is a class libary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick remarks:

- I'm pretty sure `filePath += "\\" + dateTime.Year + "\\" + dateTime.Month.ToString() + "\\" + dateTime.Day;` can be replaced by `dateTime.ToString()` with an appropriate parameter.
- Also, why are you doing a replace on `_loggerModel.file_path_pattern` when assigning its value to `filePath` and then concatenate a value to `filePath`? Do this in one go.
- I would use `string.Format` instead of concatenation to create the `filename`.
- You twice execute `Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);`. Is that an error? Because right now it looks like you're writing to the same file each time.
- The creation of a `FileTarget` and the assignment of its `Layout`, `Name` and `FileName` should move to `AddFileTarget` (you'll need to change the parameters of that method, of course).
- `FILE_WITH_STACK_TRACE`, `FILE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE`: [constants should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `Path.Combine(filePath,fileName)` is not an error. It is for the different target. Twice is okay.